# Program that checks for a valid Unix FTP Command (Not working)

Tags: c, unix

I can compile this program in Unix (Sun-Solaris) to be specific, but I cant get it to run (Im un a Unix course and all of our programs/assignments are to be done on the schools servers). Hes only been teaching us C in the last 2 weeks of the course. Im fairly new to C and cant figure out why it is not working. Any help would be appreciated. I did some research on the error but unfortunately the methods I tried/found online either didnt work or im not doing them properly.

Code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

char** splitString(char* inputString, const char delim) {
    char** output = 0;
    size_t c = 0;
    char* temp = inputString;
    char* final_space = 0;
    char delimiter[2];
    delimiter[0] = delim;
    delimiter[1] = 0;

    while(*temp) {
        if(delim == *temp) {
            c++;
            final_space = temp;
        }
        temp++;
    }

    c += final_space < (inputString + strlen(inputString) - 1);

    c++;

    output = malloc(sizeof(char*) * c);

    if(output) {
        size_t index = 0;
        char* output = strtok(inputString, delimiter);

        while(output) {
            assert(index < c);
            *(output + index++) = strdup(output);
            output = strtok(0, delimiter);
        }
        assert(index == c - 1);
        *(output + index) = 0;
    }

    return output;
}

void main() {
    char input[50];
    char** splitInput = NULL;

    int rs;

    printf("please enter a Unix FTP cmd. The program will check to see if it is a valid cmd: ");
    gets(input);

    splitInput = splitString(input, ' ');

    printf("input[%s]", *(splitInput));

    rs = strcmp(*(splitInput), "ascii");
    if(rs == 0) {
        printf("ascii is a valid ftp command\n");
        return;
    }
    rs = strcmp(*(splitInput), "recv");
    if(rs == 0) {
        printf("recv is a valid ftp command\n");
        free(splitInput);
        printf("the entered cmd is %s", *(splitInput + 1));
        return;
    }
    rs = strcmp(*(splitInput), "get");
    if(rs == 0) {
        printf("get is a valid ftp command\n");
        free(splitInput);
        printf("the entered cmd is %s", *(splitInput + 1));
        return;
    }
    rs = strcmp(*(splitInput), "send");
    if(rs == 0) {
        printf("send is a valid ftp command\n");
        free(splitInput);
        printf("the entered cmd is %s", *(splitInput + 1));
        return;
    }
    rs = strcmp(*(splitInput), "put");
    if(rs == 0) {
        printf("put is a real Unix FTP cmd\n");
        free(splitInput);
        printf("the entered cmd is %s", *(splitInput + 1));
        return;
    }
    rs = strcmp(*(splitInput), "rmdir");
    if(rs == 0) {
        printf("rmdir is a real Unix FTP cmd\n");
        printf("the entered cmd is %s", *(splitInput + 1));
        return;
    }
    rs = strcmp(*(splitInput), "mkdir");
    if(rs == 0) {
        printf("mkdir is a real Unix FTP cmd\n");
        free(splitInput);
        printf("the entered cmd is %s", *(splitInput + 1));
        return;
    }
    rs = strcmp(*(splitInput), "rmdir");
    if(rs == 0) {
        printf("rmdir is a real Unix FTP cmd\n");
        free(splitInput);
        printf("the entered cmd is %s", *(splitInput + 1));
        return;
    }
    rs = strcmp(*(splitInput), "ls");
    if(rs == 0) {
        printf("ls a real Unix FTP cmd\n");
        free(splitInput);
        printf("the entered cmd is %s", *(splitInput + 1));
        return;
    }
    rs = strcmp(*(splitInput), "cd");
    if(rs == 0) {
        printf("cd is a real Unix FTP cmd\n");
        free(splitInput);
        printf("the entered cmd is %s", *(splitInput + 1));
        return;
    }
    rs = strcmp(*(splitInput), "status");
    if(rs == 0) {
        printf("status is a valid ftp command\n");
        return;
    }
    rs = strcmp(*(splitInput), "quit");
    if(rs == 0) {
        printf("quit is a valid ftp command\n");
        return;
    } else {
        printf(*(splitInput), " isn't a real Unix FTP cmd");
    }

    return;

}
```

This is a screenshot of the error I get: [Error inside PuTTy console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSxmj.png)

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? It's an essential tool which should be your first stop before asking. Your question isn't about C, but a wall of code dump.

Comment: There are likely other problems, but I'm sure this line is wrong: `*(output + index++) = strdup(output);`  strdup makes a copy of the string output, and you're trying to assign it to the location specified by a single character value.  That is certain to cause a crash.

Comment: `while(*temp) {`Have you heard about`for()` loops? They can be handy.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting segmentation fault as your pointer is accessing memory in space that isn't allocated for.  As bruceg pointed out that line definitely caused the crash and perhaps more after that...

If your code is just to validate ftp commands, you could do the following simply with strtok or strtok_r, run "man strtok" to see details and examples.

here's the code that you can compile and run, you can finish the rest from here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    char input[50];

    int i;
    char *token,*str,*cmd[2],*ptr;

    printf("please enter a Unix FTP cmd. The program will check to see if it is a valid cmd: ");
    fgets(input,50,stdin);
    input[strlen(input)-1]='\0';

    for (i=0,str=input;;i++,str=NULL) {
        token=strtok_r(str," ",&ptr);
        if (token==NULL) { 
            break;
        }
        cmd[i]=token;
    }

    printf("(%s)\n",cmd[0]);
    if (!strcmp(cmd[0],"ascii")) {
       printf("ascii is a valid ftp command\n");
    }
    else if (!strcmp(cmd[0],"get")) {
        printf("get is a valid ftp command\n");
        printf("the entered cmd is: %s %s\n",cmd[0],cmd[1]);
    }
}
```

Btw, you should be able to do this outside of school lab with gcc either on mac or linux.  If you are on Windows install gcc in cygwin is one of the quick way.  Your code will compile on school's solaris servers.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I cant figure out how to implement the code you gave me, whichever way I try causes an error. I did however throw it in a debugger, which gave me errors at line 46 and 61. Here is my debugger console I used with my code: https://onlinegdb.com/HJE6eZK2f

Screenshot of the errors I got: http://prntscr.com/j8bb1q

Comment: there's quite a lot to fix with the way you use pointers... and it seems unnecessary to just simulate ftp and validate its commands... let me post a working code that you can compile with and go from there.